# Python list to data frame

Tags: python

I want to convert my list to a dataframe.The challenge is that the items in my list is as below and I need to extract the string value of each item of the list to a column of a data frame.

List looks like

```
Keyword = [('Hello',2.0),('Welcome',3.0),('To',3.0),('Python',4.0)]
```

Need the Dataframe as

Output:

```
     Keyword  Score
0    Hello    2.0
1    Welcome  3.0
2    To       3.0
3    Python    4.0
```

Can someone please throw some solution.

Comment: i dont see any work on your end.

Answer (score 4):

Use `columns=["Keyword", "Score"]`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
Keyword = [ ('Hello',2.0),('Welcome',3.0),('To',3.0),('Python',4.0)]
df = pd.DataFrame(Keyword, columns=["Keyword", "Score"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Keyword  Score
0    Hello    2.0
1  Welcome    3.0
2       To    3.0
3   Python    4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [pandas Dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) you can proceed as follows:

```
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(Keyword, columns=["Keyword", "Score"])
```

The result is the following:

[image: script result]

**NOTE:** you really should consider using lowercase variable names.